# Angular Ui.router $state template ng-models are $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm getting a very weird issue where the ui-view template of my $state controller is interacting with the $rootScope, rather than $scope.

BUT it will injest $scope variables at init time.

for example:
if I have  $scope.name = "test"

and in my template

```
<input ng-model="name">
```

the input will successfully have "test" inserted fine.

however, when I have a $scope.$watch("name") it does not fire, instead only $rootScope watch on "name" will fire... Did I wire my routes incorrectly?

I have a main "app" that gets its main dependency (my component):

```
angular.module('p1poc', ['ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial', 'ngWebSocket' ... 'myModule');
```

The module in question is "myModule":

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router', 'infinite-scroll', 'pasvaz.bindonce'])

  .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('search', {
      url: '/search?query',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
      label: 'Search',
      access: {free: true}
    });
  }])
```

as you can see, I am injecting the controller in, as well as the template

my template as for example html elements like such:

```
  <md-select placeholder="Sort By" ng-model="orderBy">
                <md-option value="_score" checked>Relevance</md-option>
                <md-option value="citingsrcscount">Cited Count</md-option>
                <md-option value="sortdate">Publication Date</md-option>
              </md-select>
```

But as I described above, the ng-model updates $rootScope.orderBy rather than $scope.orderBy.

but at init time, it is successfully getting data from $scope.orderBy...just not bound 2 ways

Comment: What's your controller code look like? Also I'm not familiar with `md-select` but if it offers the `ng-change` attribute you don't have to worry about setting the watch up yourself

Comment: yes adding ng-change functions seem to fix the issue...but still wondering if  i wired it incorrectly

Comment: If you're able to access `$scope` data you declared in `MainCtrl` in your template then I'd say everything is probably set up correctly but I don't want to say for sure without seeing your controller code and the html with the `ui-view` that your template is placed into

Answer (score 0):

try assigning an empty value for the $scope.name before you are going to use it in HTML